# WordPress not showing HTML tags

Tags: html, wordpress, tags

I am new to WordPress and I am having difficulties posting HTML tags on a blog. Each time I post something with HTML or the tags given it throws me a 403 mod_security error but if I post without the html or tags, it post properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/quick-examples.html) configuration something is blocking the tags.

Comment: yes you were right.I called the hosting service and they patched things on their side.

Comment: @trevy Please choose my answer at the left side of the screen (green arrow) so that your question has been answered correctly.